# Mount point space is not the same as the HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, mountpoint

I'm new to linux and I have question about mount point

I have two HDD in my system, one 500GB and one 1TB

The 500 is used for OS and swap, the 1TB is for storage only

the 500GB is name sda1 and 1TB is sdb1

I first  mount the 1TB drive to /media/sdb1 Then I create a folder and add some test file in.  I then I unmount it and remount it to /media/DATA. However, in media folder, sdb1 folder is still exists with folder and test file I added in earlier. I also have DATA folder with nothing inside. Is this normal? I was expecting that I should get my folder + test data in the DATA folder when I remount and the sdb1 folder should be gone. Also free space in both sdb1 folder and DATA folder shows only about 400+GB. If this is really the 1TB HDD, I should get 900+GB of free space. Moreover, looking in GParted, it's shows that 500GB HDD is mounted to / and  1TBHDD is mounted to /media/DATA with 14GB used space. 14GB?? I didn't add in anything yet, how can it already use 14 GB?

Is there anyway to tell if the folder (mount point) is actually the 1TB drive?

Here is the result of a mount command

```
  /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota,acl,user_xattr)
  proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
  sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
  none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
  none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
  none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
  udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
  devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
  tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
  none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
  none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
  gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/chin/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon   (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=chin)
  /dev/sr0 on /media/HPSS870B_64 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks)
```

sdb1 doesn't even exist here

Thanks

Comment: If you run `mount` on the command line (with no arguments), does the volume appear to be mounted where you expect?

Comment: I added the result of a mount command to the question

Comment: sbd1 isn't listed in mount command, but Gparted said it's mounted. Which one is true?

Comment: The `mount` command is definitive.  It sounds a lot like you've just been creating files on the `/` volume under `/media` rather than having another volume mounted there.

Comment: I don't know what happen, I restarted the computer and now when I click into DATA drive (from file manager) it's said 900+ GB now and sdb1 folder is gone. so I guess it's working now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Since I already got an answer to this problem, do I have to answer my own question? But I didn't do any thing apart from restarting it again. Please advice